# iOS 7 Control Center maybe prevents redraw

Tags: ios7

I have a custom button, extends from UIControl that handles touchesBegan and touchesEnded with changing the background color. Normally this buttons works fine, but if it is positioned on the bottom of the screen, the color change in touchesBegan is not rendered or rendered delayed. I called setNeedsDisplay, but no change. I implemented the drawRect function and this function isn't called too.
I noticed that the default UIButton has the same behavior. Moving the button up about 25 Pixels the behavior is normal again.

I'm not sure, but I think this is caused by the Control-Center. Maybe because there's the swipe up recognition area or something else??
Can someone confirm this, or have I a mystery bug in my app? Is there an other opportunity than moving my bottom-buttons up?